# How can I re-define type conversion from pointer A to point B?

Tags: c++

I am trying to be able to swap implementation for A.

We have old code use interface like:

```
class A;
class B 
{
A* CreateA();
};
```

We want to have

```
class AImpl;

template<typename Impl = AImpl>
class A: public Impl
{
public:
  A(const Impl& a) : Impl(a) {}
};

template<typename Impl = BImpl>
class B : public Impl
{
A* CreateA();
};
```

where BImpl only have

```
AImpl* BImpl::CreateA();
```

I am sure we can add:

```
A* B::CreateA() { return (A*)BImpl::CreateA();}
```

but what if there are a lot of different version of CreateA and I am lazy? Is there a way we can define a type converter in AImpl that can implicitly convert AImpl* to A*? so that code like following won't break:

```
A* pA = BImpl::CreateA();
```

Comment: First line you say "B as implementation of A", but second line, the code you provide is "A implementation of B", is there a mistake ?

Comment: You want to create a base class, and access it through a derived class pointer? That's pretty much opposite polymorphism.

Comment: Yep, I don't really want polymophism in this case.  It is just a pimpl.

Comment: I can change public to private in this case, but I am just lazy, I don't want to rewrite a lot of code in A/B just to call the same function in the impl.